# I have two version of python installed on my computer but one is not responding

Tags: python, windows, import, anaconda

I have two version of python installed on my computer one is `3.6.0` **Anaconda** and another one is `3.6.3`. Now on 3.6.3 I can not run or import any library like `pandas` or `numpy` on IDLE. I use windows 10. I can work on 3.6 version [Anaconda]. I tried to change the version through command prompt by `py -3` but since both the version are in 3 + so it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two versions of Python 3 on the same machine you should use virtual environments.

This will keep them separate and allow you to use the one you want and install the modules you want on that version.

You can learn to do this here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: The OP is saying they *already have* two separate interpreters -- this is a distinct situation from *wanting to have* two separate sets of installed libraries backed by the same interpreter.

Comment: I know, but if they create virtual environments they can use one from each interpreter, the same way you have a venv for py2 and one for py3

Answer (score 3):

Remove the Anaconda Python `3.6.0` python path from your `PATH` environment variables.
Instead, add the Python `3.6.3` path to your `PATH` variable.

Now use your normal command prompt for Python `3.6.3` version.
Use the command `activate root` in command prompt When you need Python `3.6.0` version.